# Does $ \ (g^a Mod\ p)^b\, $ $\equiv$ $ \ (g^a)^b (Mod\ p)\, $ hold true?

Tags: modules, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Are these two equations:
$$
\ (g^a Mod\ p)^b\,
$$

$$
\ (g^a)^b (Mod\ p)\,
$$
one and the same? If yes then how And if no then how to solve the first equation?

Comment: I assume by $x \bmod y$ you mean the remainder when $x$ is divided by $y$? (do you take the remainder in $0 \leq r < y$?) And by "solve" are you just asking how to do arithmetic, or is there more you haven't written? If it's just arithmetic, you do it the way you normally do: one operation at a time, possibly with shortcuts if you see the possibility to use them. (e.g. computing a modular exponentiation rather than computing an exponentiation followed by a remainder, because you know both ways give the same value)

Comment: i want to know,how do we solve this (3^5 Mod 7)^11 step by step ?
and is it true that (3^5 Mod 7)^11 is equivalent to "(3^5)^11 (Mod 7)" which is "3^55 (Mod 7)" or "x^ab (Mod p)"

Comment: Go quickly to the FAQ section and read how to write properly mathematics in this site using LaTeX, otherwise your question runs the risk of not being read, leave alone addressed, by many people.

Comment: Your question is addressed by a repeated application of the following easily proved fact: If $a\equiv a'\pmod n$ and $b\equiv b'\pmod n$, then $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod n\,$.

Comment: Notice that there are no equations in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following builds on Lubin's answer. Due to a rule called the congruence of powers, proven [here](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/modular-arithmetic-and-diffie-hellman/#congruence-of-powers), if x mod p = y mod p then $$ x^r\ mod\ p = y^r\ mod\ p$$
Therefore, if we can show that ($g^a$ mod p) **mod p**=$g^a$ **mod p** then the not bold bits are x and y and we can raise them to the power of b and they will both yield the same result when they are fed into mod p.